# Creating dynamic list element php

Tags: php, html-lists, concatenation

I need to generate `li` item with `data-` attribute while `array.length < 0`
Got a problem while concatenation. In result it's wrong `li`
I need: `<li data-color='red, green, blue' data-size='1, 2, 3'>` 
But result is: `<li data- color='red, green, blue' size='1, 2, 3'>`

Code:

```
$filters_li = '<li class="textile-item"';

                foreach($filters_labels as $label){
                    foreach($filters_fields as $field){
                        $filters_li .= 'data-'.$label.'="'. get_labels_as_tags($field, 1) . '"';
                    }
                }

                $filters_li .= '>';
```

Where is problem, I can't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try trimming the $label to see your results like so :

```
    filters_li = '<li class="textile-item"';

                foreach($filters_labels as $label){
                    foreach($filters_fields as $field){
                        $filters_li .= 'data-'. trim($label) .'="'. get_labels_as_tags($field, 1) . '"';
                    }
                }

                $filters_li .= '>';
```

Maybe that does the trick for you

Answer (score 1):

you can use from trim function, this function remove spaces by default

```
$filters_li .= 'data-'.trim($label).'="'. get_labels_as_tags($field, 1) . '"';
```